# Conceptual questions about standardization/preprocessing

Tags: machine-learning, standardization, data-imputation, data-preprocessing

I have a datset consisting of:

1. float column (seems like continuous variable with some outliers in range $[1000, 20000]$. I plotted its density curve, looks like close to normal)
2. integer column (seems like discrete variable with range in $[0, 100]$.
3. categorical column with categories like $"x< 10", \;"10\leq x < 20", \;"20\leq x < 30", "x\geq 30"$. Note that these categories have a natural order.
4. another categorical column with a total of 4 categories, but the categories here are simple labels, which don't have any natural order.
5. target column is binary (0/1)

I'll try to fit KNN on this dataset but before doing that, I have the following conceptual concepts on data preprocessing:

1. I'm definitely going to standardize the float column (subtract mean and divide by standard deviation)
2. Should I standardize the integer column? If I do this, then it would change from integer to float column. This is where I'm struggling to understand whether or not it is justified to touch this column.
3. How do I treat the first categorical columns where categories have natural order? How do I translate the categories $"x<10"$ or $"10 \leq x < 20$ so that I can feed it into sklearn's KNeighboursClassifier ?
4. I'm going to do one hot encoding for the second categorical column, because I couldn't find anything better.

**Note that before preprocessing my data, I'm going to train_test split it. So after training my model, how should I evaluate it on my test set. Will it be fine if I use the same mean/std obtained from train set to scale the float column of the test dataset, and treat the categorical columns of test set the same way I did for train set?**

Please help me with these doubts as I'm a beginner in Machine Learning.

Answer (score 1):

**Should I standardize the integer column?**

It doesn't matter whether it is integer or float, until and unless the feature is continuous, you can use standardization/normalization. While using algorithms like KNN which is primarily based on distance, it is better to standardize the numerical data

**How do I treat the first categorical columns where categories have natural order?**

First understand whether your categories are ordinal or nominal.
If your categories are ordinal you can go with label encoding, otherwise one hot encoding.

**How do I translate the categories "x<10" or "10≤x<20 so that I can feed it into sklearn's KNeighboursClassifier ?**

If you have 20+ categories you can choose to bin them into different groups based on their relationship, which will get you out of curse of dimensionality problem.